# Does diagonals exceeds the entire matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, trace

Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ be a matrix whose entries are nonnegative. Also, let $d=\text{diag}(A)$. Is $\frac{1}{n}\mathbf{1}^{\top}\text{diag}(A)\mathbf{1} - \frac{1}{n^2}\mathbf{1}^{\top}A\mathbf{1} \geq 0$ where $\mathbf{1}$ is a vector of all one? If not under what condition on $A$ it would be true?

**My try**

$$
\text{trace}(\frac{1}{n}\mathbf{1}^{\top}\text{diag}(A)\mathbf{1} - \frac{1}{n^2}\mathbf{1}^{\top}A\mathbf{1})=\frac{1}{n}\text{trace}(\mathbf{1}\mathbf{1}^{\top}\text{diag}(A))-\frac{1}{n^2}\text{trace}(\mathbf{1}\mathbf{1}^{\top}A)
$$

Comment: You need for example that the diagonal elements are bigger than the average of all other elements on the same row

Comment: Strange question. What if $A$ has a zero diagonal and nonzero off-diagonal elements?

Comment: @user1551: We can exclude this case.

Comment: @Exodd: How do you conclude it?

Comment: We can rewrite the inequality as 
$$
\frac 1{n^2}\mathbf 1^T \left(n \operatorname{diag}(A) - A \right)\mathbf 1 \geq 0.
$$
In other words, you're asking whether $n \operatorname{diag}(A) - A$ is always a matrix whose entries have a non-negative sum. As I believe user1551 is getting at, the answer is obviously no unless we have some severe restriction on the possible entries of $A$.

Comment: If $B$ denotes $A - \operatorname{diag}(A)$ (a matrix whose diagonal entries are zero), then we can also write this inequality as $(n-1)1^T\operatorname{diag}(A) 1 \geq 1^TB1$, or if you prefer, $(n-1) \cdot 1^Td\geq 1^TB1$.